# Swagger: how to represent a property whose type is oneOf a list of types?

Tags: swagger, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have an object that has a property that is an object whose type would be one of list of types. All my attempts have been rejected by Swagger Editor with the following error:

```
Data does not match any schemas from 'anyOf'
Jump to line 43
Details
Object
code: "ANY_OF_MISSING"
message: "Data does not match any schemas from 'anyOf'"
path: Array [7]
inner: Array [2]
level: 900
type: "Swagger Error"
description: "Data does not match any schemas from 'anyOf'"
lineNumber: 43
```

The full swagger specification file is as follows (the field in question is `DataSetsInquiryRsp.dataSets.dataSet`):

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: My API
  description: My Awesome API
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /dataSetsInquiry:
    get:
      description: Retrieve one or more data-sets.
      parameters:
        - name: ids
          in: query
          description: List of identifiers of requested data-sets.
          required: true
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Requested data-sets.
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/DataSetsInquiryRsp'
        default:
          description: Unexpected error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
definitions:
  DataSetsInquiryRsp:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      sessionIdentifier:
        description: Identifier of the secure session with the server.
        type: number
      dataSets:
        type: object
        additionalProperties: false
        properties:
          id:
            type: string
          dataSet:
            type: array
            items:
              oneOf:
              - $ref: '#/definitions/Customer'
              - $ref: '#/definitions/Merchant'
  Customer:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      firstName:
        description: First name of the customer
        type: string
      lastName:
        description: Last name of the customer
        type: string
  Merchant:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
      code:
        description: Code the Merchant.
        type: string
      name:
        description: Name of the Merchant.
        type: string
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [oneOf in Swagger schema does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872277/oneof-in-swagger-schema-does-not-work)

Comment: My question was on 2015, the question you pointed as being duplicated by mine has been asked on 2016. What is duplicate of what? Besides, I have already answered the question and explained the source of the error I have encountered!

Comment: That question and answers has some more details, specifically, that `oneOf`/`anyOf` is now supported in OpenAPI 3.0. Just linking it here for future visitors.

Comment: Marking my question as duplicate of a newer question is not accurate. It would be better to either update my answer and make reference to the response to the newer question. Or use another mechanism that is accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the issue is simply the fact that `Swagger` doesn't support `oneOff`. In fact, `Swagger` supports a subset of `Json-Schema` and add a few things (datatype `file` for instance).

What is bad here is the error returned by `Swagger`. It doesn't help match. And this is the case of all `Json-Schema` validators I have worked with so far: [`is-my-json-valid`](https://github.com/mafintosh/is-my-json-valid), [`jsen`](https://github.com/bugventure/jsen).