# oneOf in Swagger schema does not work

Tags: yaml, swagger, jsonschema

I want to define `PaymentMethod` as below. Is oneOf supported in swagger.yaml?

```yaml
PaymentMethod:
      oneOf:
        - $ref: '#/definitions/NewPaymentMethod'
        - $ref: '#/definitions/ExistPaymentMethod'
```

The `ExistPaymentMethod` will have just id, and `cardNumber` where `NewPaymentMethod` will have no `id`, but all other details, e.g. `cardNumber`, `cardholderName`, `cardholderAddress` etc.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`oneOf` is supported in OpenAPI version 3 (`openapi: 3.0.0`), but not in Swagger version 2 (`swagger: '2.0'`).

```yaml
PaymentMethod:
  oneOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/NewPaymentMethod'
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ExistPaymentMethod'
```

GitHub issue ref: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/333

For a list of changes in OpenAPI 3.0 compared to 2.0, see: https://blog.readme.io/an-example-filled-guide-to-swagger-3-2/

Answer (score 6):

What Swagger uses is only inspired by JSON Schema.  They haven't deviated too much from JSON Schema, but they leave some things out, add some things, and change some behaviors.  One of the things Swagger leaves out is `oneOf`.

More details can be found at http://swagger.io/specification/#schemaObject

Comment: This answer is outdated - `oneOf` is now supported in OpenAPI 3.0, as explained in [Evan Torkos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44534699/113116).

Answer (score 3):

OneOf, anyOf and other similar directives are not supported swagger 2.0, but supported in Open API 3.0 specifications.

You will need to convert your Swagger 2.0 file to Open API 3.0 file.

Here is the link -
https://blog.runscope.com/posts/tutorial-upgrading-swagger-2-api-definition-to-openapi-3

Here is one more useful link -
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3803