# how to allow more than one type in a property using Swagger?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I'm using Swagger, one of the Open API tools to define an API.

For example, I have an object `NameValue` `{ propertyName: propertyValue}`

How to let Sagger allow propertyValue could be integer, string, boolean.

```
NameValue:
   type: "object"
   required:
     - "propertyName"
   properties:
     propertyName:
       type: allow integer, string, boolean.
```

I have try

```
   propertyName:
    oneOf:
      - type: "integer"
      - type: "string"
      - ypte: "boolean"
```

But it does not work. I have searched the google, but find nothing about this.

Comment: Are you using `swagger: "2.0"` or `openapi: 3.0.0`?

Comment: @Helen Swagger "2.0"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [oneOf in Swagger schema does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872277/oneof-in-swagger-schema-does-not-work)

Comment: See the linked question. `oneOf` and `anyOf` are only supported in OpenAPI 3.0 but not in OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0.

Comment: @Helen I think this is a different question. Because what I want to achieve is to specify a value to be more than one type. The link question is specify an entity to be more than one kind.

Comment: It's exactly the same question. And the answer is the same - you need `oneOf` as in your 2nd example, but it's only supported in `openapi: 3.0.0` but not `swagger: '2.0'`. (Your 2nd example is a valid OpenAPI 3.0 property definition).