# Customising a Components object - OpenAPI

Tags: api, yaml, swagger, openapi

Is it possible to assign a customised name to a Components object in OpenAPI?

I currently have two Component objects that specify a request schema:

```
Request1:
type: object
description: Request 1
properties:
  a:
    description: Filter 1 a
    $ref: '#/definitions/Filter1a'
  b:
    description: Filter 1 b.
    $ref: '#/definitions/Filter1b'
 


Request2:
    type: object
    description: Request 2
    properties:
      query:
        type: object
        description: Filter 2.
        properties:
            bool:
              type: object
              properties:
                  must:
                    type: array
                    items:
                      type: object
                      properties:
                        match_all:
                          type: object
```

In the endpoint description I refer to these schemas as follows:

```
/v2/myEndpoint: 
    post: 
      tags: 
        - some tags
      operationId: someId
      summary: Some summary
      description: Some description 
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters: 
        - in: body
          name: body
          required: false
          schema:
            oneOf:
              - $ref: '#/definitions/Request1'
              - $ref: '#/definitions/Request2'
```

When I publish the yaml file, the UI shows Request1 and Request2 in selection tabs, which carry the names 'Request1' and 'Request2'. Is it possible to assign custom names to them, so that the UI will show the custom names instead? For example 'Custom name request 1' and 'Custom name request 2'?

Many thanks!

Comment: FYI, OpenAPI 2.0 [does not have `oneOf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44534699/113116). You need OpenAPI 3 to use `oneOf`.

Comment: Thanks, I have amended this!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant Swagger UI.

`title` would do that. [Link to Open Api Spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/schemas/v3.0/schema.yaml#L206).

```
Request1:
 title: Custom name request 1
 type:...

Request2:
 title: Custom name request 2
 type:...
```

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly what I needed! Thank you!